# MVVM Cross version 8 displaying the view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

I'm new to using MVVM Cross and I'm trying to get the basics.  My confusion comes in with seeing my view.  I have a main view that is a menu bar with a few menu items with a different color background.  That is my main view.  I've watched a few videos online and study the tip calculator example, but none of those really point to how the view "shows" when the application runs.  It seems a bit magical.  So I know I'm missing something.

Now what I did figure out is if I use the ViewPresenter attributes, I can get my main view to display over the main window.  But, without those attributes, all I get is the main window. The tip calculator example does not show any attributes so again I think I'm missing something.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this? I'm having the same problem and I'm sure that the viewmodel is correctly attaching to the view, it's just that there seems to be something missing to have the actual view show up and it's not in the docs

Comment: I did not solve this.  Instead, I implemented my own MVVM watching a few SingletonSean videos.  My application is small, so I didn't need to use the MVMCross library.  Plus doing it this way, I learned how MVVM actually works.

Answer (score 0):

`MvxApplication.RegisterAppStart<TViewModel>()` in the Core project is telling MvvmCross the ViewModel to start with. MvvmCross can use [convention](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-note-about-views-and-viewmodels) to find the view for the ViewModel, or the more modern approach would be to use the view presenter attributes. TipCalc was written before the view presenter attributes and has not been upgraded to use them.

There is general documentation about view presenters [here](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/view-presenters). Each platform has specifics.

For example, Android has activity + fragments. Activity is like a window. Fragment is like a user control. MvvmCross would automatically create the host activity for your fragment as needed when you use the IMvxNavigationService to navigate to your fragment ViewModel. There is more information avaiable in the MvvmCross [documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/android/android-view-presenter).